# OSRM. Calculate the distance between two points by setting the bearings

Tags: osrm

I need to calculate the distances between 2 cameras, I know the azimuths (bearings) of these cameras, so in bearings I set two values

> https://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/37.803292,55.810219;37.624094,55.730463.json?steps=false&geometries=geojson&annotations=true&overview=full&bearings=86,0

When I click on the link, I get the following error:

> {"message":"Number of elements in bearings size 1 does not match coordinate size 2","code":"InvalidOptions"}

Answer (score 2):

One bearing is set with two values: degree and bearing range.
For example, bearings=86,0 means bearing is 86 degrees with no range.
And, bearings=100,20 means bearing is in the range from 80 to 120.

You have to add a second bearing in the URL,
something like: bearings=86,10;0,10 where the range is +/-10 around the degree, for example.